# How to find the shortest word in a list in python?

Tags: python

I want this function returns the word in the list which has the least characters.

Here is what I coded:

```
def get_shortest_name(words):
    shortest_word = ""
    shortest_length = 0
    for word in words:
        if shortest_length > len(word):
            shortest_length = len(word)             
            shortest_word = word 
    return shortest_word

def test_get_shortest_name():
    print("1.", get_shortest_name(["Candide", "Jessie", "Kath", "Amity", "Raeanne"]))
```

output: 1. Kath

I got a correct output, but failed for other hidden tests. Please help me to figure out some problems in my code. Many thanks!

Comment: Which "hidden tests" fail?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't return "Kath", it returns an empty string. It doesn't work at all. If you want help debugging your code, you have to post your actual code.

Comment: Nothing will be shorter than `""`.

Comment: You can init `shortest_word` with the first word in list and `shortest_length` with its length

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

```py
def get_shortest_name(words):
    shortest_word = ""
    shortest_length = 0
```

You start with a shortest length of `0`, so... How could **any** word have a length that is shorter that this? A first solution would be using some hard-coded value like

```py
shortest_length = 999
```

However, this would assume there could never be any word shortest word with a length that is greater than `999`...

Another option:

```py
shortest_length = float('inf')
```

You are sure any word's length is smaller that infinity.

---

**Bonus: One liner**

You can actually reduce all your function to a single line:

```py
shortest_word = min(words, key=lambda word: len(word))
```

I'll let you check out python's [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) builtin function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correct version of your code. It might help you to see what was wrong with your own code. I have denoted the modified lines by a comment `#`. Except the two modified lines, everything stays the same. The problem in your code was that `""` was the shortest word which you initialized and hence no other word was selected as the shortest because all of them had finite length (size).

```
def get_shortest_name(words):
    shortest_word = words[0] # Choose first word as the smallest as starting point
    shortest_length = len(shortest_word) # Get the length of first word
    for word in words:
        if shortest_length > len(word):
            shortest_length = len(word)             
            shortest_word = word 
    return shortest_word

def test_get_shortest_name():
    print("1.", get_shortest_name(["Candide", "Jessie", "Kath", "Amity", "Raeanne"])) 

test_get_shortest_name()
```

**Output**

```
1. Kath
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by  word length. No one can ensure only one shortest word in list

```
print(sorted(["Candide", "Jessie", "Kath" ,"Amity", "Raeanne"],key=lambda x: len(x)))
```